# Asp.net core - Two-factor authentication login process

Tags: asp.net-core, two-factor-authentication

I could apply two-factor authentication for user in my asp.net core app, but in the login phase, I have a problem with this logic:

- if a user disables 2FA feature -> Directly login.
- if a user enables 2FA feature -> Show 2FA input field.

I know that it's impossible to check whether users disable or enable 2FA before logging in. Then how to check this after a user enters correct username and password but still unauthorized if user enables 2FA?

Comment: If I understood your question right, you don't want to redirect the user, and want to show the 2FA input field to the user on the same page, right?

Comment: Yes, but I found a solution for this myself. If you know something, just share here. Thanks.

Comment: Did u ever figure out what to do here ive come across the same thing @HoàngNguyễn ive come across the same UI issues of login showing first instead of 2fa for already authenticated user.